# Canvas.drawPoint() not working if there's Canvas.rotate(90)?

Tags: android

So i'm making a custom View that displays some graphs (plots), and in some ocasions i want to rotate the canvas 90 degrees.
All i can guess is that there's a bug in my device (HTC Desire, with android 2.3), i haven't test it yet in another device.

```java
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate((float) 90.0);
    canvas.drawPoint(10, 10, pointPaint); /* Sorry about missing that these
            * coordinates will fall out after being rotated... it's just an
            * example. put 10, -10 and it should work, but it doesn't */
    canvas.restore();
}
```

This won't draw the point, but if we change that 90.0 for a 90.014 (i found that this was the minimum, 90.013 doesn't work either) then the point will show up.

So... is it something i'm doing wrong, or it's just Android's bug? I googled a lot, but couldn't find nothing....

-Victor -

edit: Additional info: Only points doesn't work. Rects, lines and circles work perfect.
edit: screenshot of my app, you can see how the red line has dots on the 90.014 degree version, and the 90.0 doesn't.:
[image]

(As you can see, the 90.014 it looks like a little bit flipped (you can see how the Y axis is 'broken')

Comment: Could you please set the `Paint` cap of the points to round: `paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND)`, so we can narrow down the problem?

Comment: Yup, with Paint.Cap.ROUND it works :D. I tested .SQUARE and .BUTT and it doesn't though, but it doesn't matter, it looks like the same :3. If you put this as answer i will accept it. side question: so this is an Android bug?

Comment: I added an answer. I will try to further investigate in that, because it also seems like a bug to me, but I didn't have the time to reproduce the problem yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `Paint` of the dots to use a `ROUND` stroke cap resolves the problem, even though it doesn't yet explain the strange behavior you are experiencing. e.g.:

```
paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND)
```

Answer (score 2):

The canvas rotates through its origin, so if you rotate your canvas by 90 degrees you are effectively rotating your view out of your screen. You should translate the canvas to the axis you want to rotate on first:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(-axispointx,-axispointy);
canvas.rotate((float) 90.0);
canvas.translate(axispointx,axispointy);
canvas.drawPoint(10, 10, pointPaint);
canvas.restore();
```

Comment: Nevermind that, those coordinates were a fake example. I put coordinates that after rotating will show up on the screen. With a line graph, you can see the lines, but not the points if rotation is 90.0... in a min i upload a screenshot....